# Looking to copy value from cell above if cell value is empty with VBA

Tags: vba

[image]  ' I am trying to have Excel recognize a blank cell and fill in with value from 
   above cell.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = .Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

For Each cell In Range("i2:j" & lastrow)
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Sub FillBlanks()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
Range("I2:J" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End Sub
```

Comment: Well it should fill all the empty cells in column I:J with the values from above. Are there blanks due to formula or there are cells which are actually empty i.e.neither value nor blank due to a formula?

Comment: They are copied and pasted special from a  pivot.

Comment: I use the isblank formula in the blank row and the values come up as true for the blank cells.

Comment: Then it should work. To check that select the range with data in Column I:J including blanks, press Ctrl + G --> Special --> Choose Blanks and click OK. Do you see blank cells in column I:J selected or you get a message the no cells were found?

Comment: It shows the blank cells. Any ideas on why VBA isn't picking them up?

Comment: The last row used variable lr is being calculated based on Column A. Is column A empty?

Comment: Column A is not empty. It has the pivot in it.

Comment: I had used with/ end with in some of the formulas above and for some reason, it wasn't recognizing the ranged. I removed that and it works now.

Comment: While you were checking the blank cells in columns I:J with Ctrl+G, repeat the whole process again and once the blank cells get highlighted, press = and up arrow key and hit Ctrl + Enter i.e. hold down the Ctrl key and then hit Enter. Do you find the the blank cells are filled with the values from above cells? If yes, the macro does the same thing.